# Pandas frequency for every weekend

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to do some time series analysis using ARIMA with exogenous variables to predict crime trends, but I'm running into an issue. I've only got date for the weekends, so my frequency is essentially 2 index entries every week, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to make that a frequency...any ideas?

So for example, I can make a daily time series with no issues

```
PeriodIndex(['2017-02-12', '2017-04-12', '2017-09-12', '2017-12-31',
             '2018-01-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-10-01',
             '2018-01-20', '2018-01-22',
             ...
             '2018-07-22', '2018-07-23', '2018-07-24', '2018-07-25',
             '2018-07-26', '2018-07-27', '2018-07-28', '2018-07-29',
             '2018-07-30', '2018-07-31'],
            dtype='period[D]', name='Row Labels', length=196, freq='D')
```

but as I'm trying to study only a weekend effect, I'd like to focus ONLY on Sarturday and Sunday, so I can then use some time series regression to examine that series.  I can do it by REMOVING variables and focusing on only one of the two...

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-27', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-10', '2018-02-17',
               '2018-02-24', '2018-03-03', '2018-03-10', '2018-03-17',
               '2018-03-24', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-07', '2018-04-14',
               '2018-04-21', '2018-04-28', '2018-05-05', '2018-05-12',
               '2018-05-19', '2018-05-26', '2018-06-02', '2018-06-09',
               '2018-06-16', '2018-06-23', '2018-06-30', '2018-07-07',
               '2018-07-14', '2018-07-21', '2018-07-28', '2018-08-04'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Row Labels', freq='W-SAT')
```

but how the hell do I get it for Saturday AND Sunday?

Comment: Could you please give an example for the data you're dealing with, and for what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would resample to daily frequency, and then use

```
weekend_only = df[df.index.weekday >= 5]
```

where `df` is a `pandas.DataFrame` with a `DateTimeIndex`.

For the `weekday` attribute 0-4 is Monday-Friday and Saturday-Sunday is 5-6.

For more information, see the [pandas user guide on Time Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html).

Comment: Ooo this works!  I assumed it would break the frequency. Thank you!